# how to obtain a set of labels from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been reading some folders labelled as train and test with positive and negative samples to use them later with train_test_split. Because it is a lot of data I wanted to extract the labels and save them into a csv file. The reason for this is that later on I want to read this csv and input it, as labels, into a ML model. My code is the following:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(trainData, trainLabels)
```

**Note:** I was not able to find what estructure does train_test_split returns, but I suppose is an array.

trainData contains a set of sentences in rows and trainLabels contains values of 0 (positive) and 1 (negative).

The problem is when I use the following command:

```
y_train.to_csv(index=False)
```

It generates me a file called ytrainE.csv that has values like:

```
"1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","0",...
```

When I read this csv file to use it into a ML model I do the following:

```
ytrain=pd.read_csv("ytrainE.csv")
```

but when I print the data the following number appears:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 0, 0.1, 1.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.2, 0.4, 1.3, 0.5, 1.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 1.5, 1.6, 0.11, 1.7, 0.12, 0.13, 1.8, 0.14, 1.9, 1.10, 0.15, 0.16, 1.11, 0.17, 0.18, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 1.15, 0.22, 0.23, 1.16, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 1.17, 1.18, 1.19, 0.27, 1.20, 0.28, 0.29, 0.30, 0.31, 0.32,
```

I suppose that it wants to read the columns and does not find anything, but I need those values in a format that I could use it for my ML model. How can I do that?

Comment: You have to tell read_csv to not expect a title row. try `ytrain=pd.read_csv("ytrainE.csv",header=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should convert `y_train` data type from `ndarray` to `DataFrame`

example code :

```py
pd.DataFrame({'label': y_train}).to_csv("y_train.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `index = False`. That will keep the column name as 0 and will not convert the values in column.